# Evaluating the integral: $\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{e^{3x}-1-3x}{x^{2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral: $$\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{e^{3x}-1-3x}{x^{2}}dx$$

I split them into three integrals, then solved them one by one,

I solved:

$I_3 = 3(\ln(0)-\ln(-1)) = 3(-\infty-i\pi)$

$I_2 = \frac{-1}{0}+1$

$I_1 = \frac{-3}{0}\cdot\frac{3e^{-3}}{-1}-3\text{Ei}(3x)$

I am not really sure how to solve the define integral for this problem.

I have precision condition the of integral $E = 10^{-4}$.

The answer should be numerical.

Comment: If numerical precision is all you want, and the integral has $|x|<1$, and the integrand looks the way it does, it's practically begging for Taylor series.

Comment: At which point I should to expand the Taylor series? The other thing I didn't understand, should I apply the series for three of them?

Comment: Hint: Taylor series for polynomials is quite trivial. Also splitting up the integrals was a mistake, you cannot do that because individually they diverge.

Comment: You mean, I need to expand the whole polynomial with Taylor series 4 times, then integrate everything separately?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the four times from, there is only one Taylor series to expand. Good advice for calculations - just do it and ask questions later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$e^{3x}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(3x)^k}{k!}=1+3x+\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{(3x)^k}{k!} $$
Your integrand becomes:
$$\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{e^{3x}-1-3x}{x^{2}}dx=\int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{3^kx^k}{k!}dx=\int_{-1}^0 \sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{3^kx^k}{x^2k!}dx=\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{3^k}{k!}\int_{-1}^0x^{k-2}dx$$
Then compute the integral and the first digits of the series.